# Define Type As Copy of Another with Different Data Types

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to find a way to define a class such that it has the same properties as another class, but with different property types (all strings), without having to enumerate the properties, and such that you can reference the properties via code rather than by a string key.

For clarification, below is an example of the functionality of what I am looking for...

```
public class ValuedClass
{
   public int Value {get; set;}
}
public class StringedClass : Stringified<ValuedClass> {}
public class Program
{
   public static void Main(int[] args)
   {
      var valued = new ValuedClass() { Value = 5 };
      var stringed = new StringedClass() { Value = "taco" };
   }
}
```

I've messed around with abstract classes w/ type arguments for each data type (ie. TNumber, TMoney, TDate, etc.), a Stingified with `this[string propName]` defined, making everything object types, and other solutions, but each one requires enumerating the properties again (thus giving another update failure point), or adds an unacceptable level of complexity to the code.

At this point, I'd think that I'd have to hijack how .net handles the code when you type `valued.Value`, and tell it to then go to `this["Value"]`, but I haven't been able to find any way to do something like that either.

Comment: `Valued<T>` and `Stringed : Valued<string>`, etc.

Comment: It would have been less typing to write all the properties.ToString(), then it would this question?

Comment: Seems to me like you want a class with a `this["xxx"]` indexer that looks up the value of the xxx property via reflection when `this[]` is accessed, or you back all your properties by a dictionary and access either the prop or the dictionary via key as you like